# Bold Top 50% of summed values & Values => 50,000

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Highlight_Top50_AND_50K()
    Dim CheckRange As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("E2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    With CheckRange
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=0.5*SUM(E:E)", Formula2:="=50,000"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Within Range (E2:E),

CONDITION 1: Bold values that are **greater than and equal to 50% of the summed values**.

CONDITION 2: Bold values that are **greater than and equal to 50,000**.

The codes ran without error but nothing is generated. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Is this supposed to work, are you following a msdn article or did you record this as a macro? Did you step through it?

Comment: @JeremyThompson I recorded it as a macro since my data is of dynamic nature.

Comment: What does "nothing is generated" signify? This code will add conditional formatting.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I'm sorry, I should have been more clear. It means to say the the conditional formatting were not applied at all when I tried to run the macro. Simply put, the values should be bolded but none are. Made me wonder if my code is somehow wrong.

Comment: Do you need the =50,000, or have tried 50000 and no equal sign because of the `Operator:=xlGreaterEqual` indicates the operator already. It's those types of things and they're fiddly with excel. Really need to confirm with the VBA Ref Doco and check the required parameters.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Tried that too. It's still not working. But this time I deleted the first formula and the values more than 50K are bolded. There's something wrong with the first formula, I'm not sure where went wrong.

Comment: When tried to run Formula1 alone, none are bolded. Confirmed that the conditional formatting is broken on first formula.

Comment: Just a more general note; but are your values going to change? If not, than you should know conditional formatting is volatile and will slow down your project significantly when you talking tons of data here. So if column E data is going to be untouched, bold it through VBA.

Comment: To continue, a simple `AutoFilter` will do in such case. Sidenote; you have opened several questions, that if answered needs to be closed. Upvote/checkmark those that have been helpfull to you which will return the favor to those who helped you out.

Comment: @JvdV Hi, yes, the values will vary. The problem is now with the first formula, which I have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Test below code and see if it works for you. The code you've posted just adds one condition and not both the conditions you have stated!

```
With CheckRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="50000"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, Formula1:="=0.5*SUM(E:E)"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe the problem is with the `Formula1:="=0.5*SUM(E:E)"` When I tried to run it alone without the other formula, it just doesn't work. I will try to modify the formula and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason i couldn't figure why one of your conditions is not working, but if it helps you this alternative should do the job

```
Sub Highlight_Top50_AND_50K()

Dim CheckRange As Range
Dim x As Range
Dim formula1 As Long

formula1 = Evaluate("=0.5*SUM(E:E)")    'define your first condition

Set CheckRange = Range("E2:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

For Each x In CheckRange
    x.Font.Bold = False
        If x >= formula1 Then   'check if greater or equal than  50% of the summed values
            x.Font.Bold = True
        End If

        If x >= 50000 Then  ' check if greater or equal to 50,000
            x.Font.Bold = True
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However it still doesn't work for this part `x.Font.Bold = False
        If x >= formula1 Then   'check if greater or equal than  50% of the summed values
            x.Font.Bold = True
        End If` I believe the formula is wrong.

Comment: that's strange, i suggest you really look at the set of numbers you have and go through them. or share a set of number as example for which you want to apply this formula
Edit. i mean to say that i cannot imagine of a case with a set of 3 or more numbers, where one of the numbers will be greater than SUM of them

Comment: I think you are right. I figure out what happened. So the condition I wanted is "Bold values that are greater than and equal to 50% of the summed values." which means to say I want the top 50% of the summed values. Say I have bunch of data in column E that sum up to 5 Millions, I only want the TOP 50%, i.e. a range of data in the column that sum up to 2.5 Millions to be bolded. EDIT: TOP LARGEST 50%

Comment: The formula is not evaluating it the way I wanted: It compares one cell to the 50% of the summed value, which is why nothing bolded in the end.

Comment: Using the same example above, it should be bold a range of data (top largest 50% of the sum) in Column E that sum up to 2.5 Millions.

Comment: i see, well that will be more difficult for me at least. I assume you will have sort the range, and then start adding the biggest with the next less biggest and repeat until these number added reach 2.5 Millions. 

Edit. Although again i think about it, you cannot make 50% of the total 5 mills , by adding the biggest numbers in descending order.

Example i have 1,2,3,4,5 . SUM 15 , 50% of SUM is 7.5.

Comment: Example i have 1,2,3,4,5 . SUM 15 , 50% of SUM is 7.5.

If i add 5+4 =9 is already higher than 50% of SUM

Comment: Yes that's outcome I needed. I have sorted the data from largest to smallest. Based on your example, the data should be shown as 5,4,3,2,1. Half of the sum is 7.5. Thus, cells contain 5 and 4 are to be bolded because the sum of them is just SUFFICIENT to cover 7.5. Anything more than that I don't need them bolded.

Comment: In my example, I only need a certain range of data that cover just enough of 2.5 Million bolded. (Top 50% Largest Values that are made up of the Cumulative Sum of the Values) I hope I articulated clearly... Something like this `If Sum("x") >= formula1 Then   'check if greater or equal than  50% of the summed values
            x.Font.Bold = True` <- This code, however, is wrong. But just to illustrate what I meant